# how does a producer know what data to publish to queues in RabbitMQ?

Tags: rabbitmq, microservices, message-queue, messagebroker, broker

How would a producer know which data to publish to consumers through queues ?
for example if a consumer wants data X from a table in the producer's database.. how does it go about getting it from the queues and how does the publisher publishes that exact wanted data in the first place, does it publish everything ??

Comment: This is a very broad question. It feels more like a question requiring a [tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/getstarted.html) for an answer.

Comment: I am not sure, but topics may be of interest, based on the notes in your question. Beyond that, it's about the consumer team talking with the producer team: "Here's what I need - is it what you've got?"; "Here's what I've got - is it what you need?" Or, maybe just "Here's what I've got - take it or leave it".

Comment: @andrewjames thank you that's already answering the question, just one note, does it go to the database and publish every table and row of data so that consumers can query the queues ? doesn't that mean we just duplicated data and shifted the load from microservice to queues ?